# Kubuntu staring cura appimage after each login despite it not running during logout. How to fix it?

Tags: kubuntu, startup, 19.10, autostart, appimage

I can't figure out why.

I like the functionality of reopening apps that were not closed before logout.

But this application starting on every logon despite me not leaving it open. I used `sudo ps -A` before logging out so I'm sure this app does not run in the background. Despite that it will start after each login/reboot.

Cura is installed from .appimage

How can I can fix that?  What I can check?

EDIT: problem persist after 19.10 update

Comment: Of course. I added `appimagekit_e2c5a07a925e9668276f846fb5d64def-cura`(as I see the process name in ps) to "Applications to be excluded from sessions" in there, but it makes no difference. I also checked "autostart" section there- no entries about cura.

Comment: I see that appimagelaucherfs is always running in the background- it may be connected. Also doesn't it suppose to run only when im running some apppimage application>?

Comment: Any idea where to look for the reason, what logs to check. In the meantime there was cura appimage update. I installed new version and removed the old one but problem persist - it's driving me crazy

Comment: Uninstall it. Restart the system. Install it again. Do you have tried that?

Comment: @SaidbakR also tried that, removed then installed newer version - still the same

Answer (score 1):

Search for clues in the `/proc/<PID>` directory. Each process has it own directory in `/proc/`. Get the processes #,
 then navigate there and look around. Other commands such as `ps -auxf`, and `pstree` could help find the culprit.

If that isn't helping then try "System settings->Desktop Session [Start with an empty session]" . Maybe after a few closed sessions you may be able to re-enable [Restore Previous Session].

I had an issue with a stubborn app doing the same thing. I feel the Plasma Desktop Restore Previous Sessions may have a few kinks that may need some more tweaking with how that behavior is handled.

If I am correct cure is a 3d slicer for generating G-code for 3d printers. It could potentially be another related app calling it.

Comment: Checking but so far no solution. Posting relevant fragments:
    `ps -auxf`
    (...)
    `thecore   8333  0.0  0.0   2612   796 ?        S    12:47   0:00 /bin/sh 
    /tmp/.mount_0003.Av0Rnyj/usr/bin//cura.sh`
    `thecore   8359  6.8  2.3 2652984 389644 ?      Sl   12:47   0:09  
\_ cura`
   `thecore   8654  0.0  0.0 125712  4416 ?        SNl  12:47   0:00     
 \_ `
  `/tmp/.mount_0003.Av0Rnyj/usr/bin/CuraEngine connect 127.0.0.1:49674`
    (...)

Comment: That was with cura running. when i close it there is no mention of it in `ps -auxf` or `pstrree`. Little confused about what the proc directory content represents.

Comment: I did not expect that - cura starts even if [Start with an empty session] is set, so probably not kde issue at all but something about appimagelauncher